# Commas in @font-face irritate Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-face, webfonts

I wanted to use a font by using the following @font-face rule:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Web Symbols';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Web Symbols'), local('WebSymbols'), url(http://localhost/Blog/webfonts/WebSymbols-Regular.otf) format('opentype');
}
```

But this does not work, FF does not use the right font, although it knows it: [image: Firebug screenshot]

But interestingly it uses the font, when I remove 1(!) comma from the `src`-rule, no matter which of both commas. Is this a bug in Firefox or am I doing something wrong? I also compared my `font-face` with some provided by [Google](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open%20Sans:400) but was not able to find any differences.

Comment: to generate cross browser font-face,  in font squirrel site by upload the font

Comment: Any CSS parsing errors in the web console?  Or a link to the page showing the problem?